# How to make first letter uppercase in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm developing an iPhone app. In a label, I want to show an user's first letter of the name uppercase. How do I do that?

Comment: Where you you want to show it? In a textbox or a label or...?

Comment: Have you checked the NSString documentation for some method that sounds like it returns a capitalized string?

Comment: If you're doing this to a last name, please keep in mind that capitalization rules of last names vary. Certain last names, like McDonald or O'Conor, have capital letters other than just the first.

Comment: Well this is for userName and on the label.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If there is only one word String, then use the method

[-capitalized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416784-capitalized)

```
let capitalizedString = myStr.capitalized // capitalizes every word
```

Otherwise, for multi word strings, you have to extract first character and make only that character upper case.

Comment: as said below : this method capitalizes every word of the `NSString`

Comment: "capitalizedString" Returns: A string with the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

Comment: If you have the string name of a database table named `yourCoolTable`, and you're after the name `YourCoolTable`, this won't work, because it returns `Yourcooltable`, which simply mangles your value in the opposite direction... fixing the first character, while trashing the rest of your characters.

Comment: Not an answer, because this solution converts the rest of the characters of the string to lowercase.

Answer (score 63):

(2014-07-24: Currently accepted answer is not correct) The question is very specific: Make the first letter uppercase, leave the rest lowercase. Using capitalizedString produces a different result: “Capitalized String” instead of “Capitalized string”. There is another variant depending on the locale, which is capitalizedStringWithLocale, but it's not correct for spanish, right now it's using the same rules as in english, so this is how I'm doing it for spanish:

```
NSString *abc = @"this is test";

abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[abc substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[abc substringFromIndex:1] ];       
NSLog(@"abc = %@",abc);
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what beryllium's answer does?

Comment: Nope, Beryllium's answer capitalises everyword of a NSString.

Comment: this will throw an exception on the empty string

Answer (score 9):

In case someone is still interested in 2016, here is a **Swift 3** extension:

```
extension String {
    func capitalizedFirst() -> String {
        let first = self[self.startIndex ..< self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]
        let rest = self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1) ..< self.endIndex]
        return first.uppercased() + rest.lowercased()
    }

    func capitalizedFirst(with: Locale?) -> String {
        let first = self[self.startIndex ..< self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]
        let rest = self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1) ..< self.endIndex]
        return first.uppercased(with: with) + rest.lowercased(with: with)
    }
}
```

Then you use it exactly as you would for the usual uppercased() or capitalized():

`myString.capitalizedFirst()` or `myString.capitalizedFirst(with: Locale.current)`

Answer (score 8):

This is for your `NSString+Util` category...

```
- (NSString *) capitalizedFirstLetter {
    NSString *retVal;
    if (self.length < 2) {
        retVal = self.capitalizedString;
    } else {
        retVal = string(@"%@%@",[[self substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString],[self substringFromIndex:1]);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You can do that with `NSString stringWithFormat`, of course. I use this weirdness:

```
#define string(...) \
[NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__]
```

Comment: There is no need to check for !self since your category method will not be called in that case.  And the first three conditions can be replaced with if ( self.length <= 1 ) return self.capitalizedString for simplicity.

Comment: You're right, but I think if the String got dealloc'ed it could be nil. Your point remains, about simplifying. Thanks

Comment: Even if the string was deallocated (which could only happen in a multithreaded context with erroneous memory management), self would remain a dangling pointer and not be nil.

Comment: No need to initialize `retVal = self`.

Answer (score 7):

Simply

```
- (NSString *)capitalizeFirstLetterOnlyOfString:(NSString *)string{
     NSMutableString *result = [string lowercaseString].mutableCopy;
     [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[[result substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to the accepted answer

[capitalizedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString) is used for making uppercase letters .

```
NSString *capitalizedString = [myStr capitalizedString]; // capitalizes every word
```

But if you have many words in a string and wants to get only first character as upper case use the below solution

```
NSString *firstCapitalChar = [[string substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];
NSString *capString = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString: capString];


// extract first character and make only that character upper case.
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a swift extension for it

```
extension NSString {
    func capitalizeFirstLetter() -> NSString {
        return self.length > 1 ?
          self.substringToIndex(1).capitalizedString + self.substringFromIndex(1) :
          self.capitalizedString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me:

```
NSString *serverString = jsonObject[@"info"];

NSMutableString *textToDisplay = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", serverString];

[textToDisplay replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[textToDisplay substringToIndex:1].capitalizedString];

cell.infoLabel.text = textToDisplay;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can Just add this extension

```
extension String {
    var capitalizedFirst: String {
        self.prefix(1).capitalized + self.dropFirst().lowercased()
    }
    var capitalizedFirstWordInSentence: String {
        let fullTextArr = self.components(separatedBy: " ")
        var allText = ""
        for i in 0..<fullTextArr.count {allText += fullTextArr[i].capitalizedFirst + " "}
        allText.removeLast()
        return allText
    }
}
```

you can just use the first one only but the second one will convert every word to the first letter to be capitalized for example:

```
let hello = "hello, world!"
print(hello.capitalizedFirstWordInSentence)
//Hello,World!
print(hello.capitalizedFirst)
//Hello, world!
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift:**

```
let userName = "hard CODE"
yourLabel.text = userName.localizedUppercaseString
```

I recommend using this localised version of uppercase, since names are locale sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Capitalized **only the 1st** letter

```
extension String {

    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        prefix(1).capitalized + dropFirst()
    }

}
```

Capitalized **each word** in sentence

```
label.text = string.capitalized
```